# Keyboard is not being dismissed: Facebook Account Kit iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, keyboard, account-kit

I have integrated Facebook Account Kit SDK v.4.26.0.

*Following is the scenario in which I am facing difficulty:*
When user clicks on sign in, Login with Phone Number controller is being presented and keyboard is appeared immediately on that screen to enter phone number. Now I tap on anywhere in the screen outside textfield & keyboard to trigger keyboard dismiss event. But from iOS 11.*, keyboard is not dismissed and if I navigate back by clicking back button, in that situation also keyboard remains open. Keyboard dismiss action works fine before iOS 11.0.

*Following are the steps I have tried to resolve this problem:*
 1. Using AKFViewController instance which is presented for authentication, I tried to execute `view.endEditing(true)` in order to dismiss keyboard from delegate methods of `AKFViewControllerDelegate`. (*This method did not worked*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed in the 4.28.0 release

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/102125683887755/